# How to use API request to turn on/off a smart switch +/- Smart EV Charger

Tags: smart-home

I am new to API.

My first project, if possible, is to be able to control a smart socket, to turn it on/off depending on if we are exporting energy to the grid.

I have been able to get the API to work, and it returns various figures:

```
{....."acpower":26.0,"yieldtoday":0.0,"yieldtotal":1.5,"feedinpower":17.0,"feedinenergy":0.0,"consumeenergy":0.0,"feedinpowerM2":0.0,"soc":16.0, ......}
```

If feedinpower >100 then turn smart switch on
If feedinpower <100 then turn smart switch off.

I have looked around at IFTTT and other places, and can not find the place where it would retrieve the data, and clarify if switch needs to be on/off. I know smartlife may be able to control my switch depending on the output.

The aim would eventually to be to control our BP smart homecharge unit, turning it on/off or change charging rate.

All I can find out at the minute is Apps that connect to each other, rather than the integrating with the API request output.

Please could you advise me on a good guide where I may find this info out.

Comment: which API are you talking about?

Comment: Also most consume smart plugs have current limits, check before you use any that they are rated high enough to control a EV charger